# Android Studio: Can I Refer to a Started Service in Java Code?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, service

I've decided to use a service for the Android Studio app I'm working on; however, I can't seem to find a way to reference the service in my project. The service will enable the mic to continuously record and using a thread, notify the user if the sound is over a certain loudness and then update the phone's location accordingly. So within the service, if the mic listens into something above a certain loudness threshold it will pass the information to the Google Maps activity. The service is a started service that starts after a button in another activity is pressed.

Is there a way to reference the service, possibly a variable within the service, from my Google Maps activity java code? Do I have to use a bounded service instead?

Answer (score 0):

You describing a service that should have connection to ui, notify it about it state and possibly allow changing it. You should you use bounded service for that, they have exactly what you need: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services